# Unit testing Spring Boot service layer bean which uses validation

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, validation, mockito

I really like the Java validation annotations to check basic validity of method arguments. My problem is how to test such a method of a service bean without starting a Spring application context which is very slow.

I understand that validation requires some validator to be executed. Normally, this is set up by the Spring Boot infrastructure when the service bean has @Validated. Is there a way to set up a unit test that sets up validation without using @SpringBootTest which creates a full context?

For example, I have an entity Thing and a service ThingService.

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @Accessors(chain=true)
public class Thing {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Min(value=5)
    private Long one;
    
    @NotNull @NotEmpty @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 3)
    private String two;
    
    public Thing(
            Long one,
            String two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
@Validated
public class ThingService {
    @Setter
    private ThingRepository repo;
    
    @Autowired
    public ThingService(ThingRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    };
    
    
    public Thing create(@NotNull Long arg, @NotNull @Valid Thing thing) {
        // Use arg to check that thing meets higher level constraints
        
        Thing savedThing = repo.save(thing);
        return savedThing;
    }
}
```

I can correctly test this using @SpringBootTest, but it is very slow

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ThingServiceTestOverkill {
    @MockBean
    private ThingRepository repo;
        
    @Autowired
    private ThingService service;
    
    @Test
    public void createSuccess() {
        when(repo.save(any(Thing.class))).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
        
        Thing thing = service.create(2L, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        
        verify(repo, times(1)).save(thing);
        assertThat(thing.getOne(), is(5L));
        assertThat(thing.getTwo(), is ("foo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createNullUser() {
        ConstraintViolationException ex = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
            service.create(null, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        });
        
        assertThat(ex.getConstraintViolations(), hasSize(1));
        ConstraintViolation<?> cv = ex.getConstraintViolations().stream().findFirst().get();
        assertThat(cv.getPropertyPath().toString(), is("create.arg"));
        assertThat(cv.getInvalidValue(), is(nullValue()));
        assertThat(cv.getMessage(), is("must not be null"));
    }
 }
```

If I try to test with a more traditional direct Mockito approach, no validation is done.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ThingServiceTestUnderkill {
    @Mock
    private ThingRepository repo;
    
    // Decided not to use @InjectMocks as it fails silently and can hide errors and bad smells
    private ThingService service;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void initializeTest() {
        service = new ThingService(repo);  // No validation wrapper used.
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createSuccess() {
        when(repo.save(any(Thing.class))).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
        
        Thing thing = service.create(2L, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        
        verify(repo, times(1)).save(thing);
        assertThat(thing.getOne(), is(5L));
        assertThat(thing.getTwo(), is ("foo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createNullUser() {
        ConstraintViolationException ex = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
            service.create(null, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        });
        
        // NEVER THROWS EXCEPTION
        
        assertThat(ex.getConstraintViolations(), hasSize(1));
        ConstraintViolation<?> cv = ex.getConstraintViolations().stream().findFirst().get();
        assertThat(cv.getPropertyPath().toString(), is("create.arg"));
        assertThat(cv.getInvalidValue(), is(nullValue()));
        assertThat(cv.getMessage(), is("must not be null"));
    }
 }
```

Is there a way to access the validation wrapping functionality of Spring Boot? Is there some other solution?

Spring boot 2.5.2, Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found a nice solution using ProxyFactory, MethodBeforeAdvice, and ExecutableValidator. It is a simple and fast way to unit test a class that uses method validation.

First, create a proxy of the class being tested and add an advice class (shown later). See @BeforeEach. This is the only extra work required.

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ThingServiceTestAOP {
    @Mock
    private ThingRepository repo;
    
    private ThingService service;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void initializeTest() {
        ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(new ThingService(repo));
        factory.addAdvice(new ValidationAdvice());
        service = (ThingService) factory.getProxy();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createSuccess() {
        when(repo.save(any(Thing.class))).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
        
        Thing thing = service.create(2L, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        
        verify(repo, times(1)).save(thing);
        assertThat(thing.getOne(), is(5L));
        assertThat(thing.getTwo(), is ("foo"));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void createNullUser() {
        ConstraintViolationException ex = assertThrows(ConstraintViolationException.class, () -> {
            service.create(null, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        });
        
        assertThat(ex.getConstraintViolations(), hasSize(1));
        ConstraintViolation<?> cv = ex.getConstraintViolations().stream().findFirst().get();
        assertThat(cv.getPropertyPath().toString(), is("create.userId"));
        assertThat(cv.getInvalidValue(), is(nullValue()));
        assertThat(cv.getMessage(), is("must not be null"));
    }
```

Now the advice class. The code in the static initializer block constructs the validator.

Note the use of Spring's LocalValidatorFactoryBean instead of javax's buildDefaultValidatorFactory. The former does a better job of determining the parameter names. The latter just calls parameters "arg0", "arg1", etc. More importantly, LocalValidatorFactoryBean gets the same names as when Spring Boot handles the validation so your asserts are testing the names generated in production.

The before method uses standard javax validation code to conduct method validation.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator;

import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

public class ValidationAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
    static private ExecutableValidator executableValidator;
    static {
        // Using the javax validation factory mostly works, but doesn't capture the parameter names
        // ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        // LocalValidatorFactoryBean uses DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer which does get the param names
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean factory = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        executableValidator = factory.getValidator().forExecutables();
        factory.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = executableValidator.validateParameters(target, method, args);
        if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Spring Boot applications, you can enable Spring Javax validation while running integration tests using ValidationAutoConfiguration class. The class is provided with Spring Boot since version 1.5.0.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.html

All required to be done is just importing the annotation only on your test classes.

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

    
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ValidationAutoConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= ThingService.class)
public class ThingServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private ThingRepository repo;
        
    @Autowired
    private ThingService service;

    @Test
    public void createSuccess() {
        when(repo.save(any(Thing.class))).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
        
        Thing thing = service.create(2L, new Thing(5L, "foo"));
        
        verify(repo, times(1)).save(thing);
        assertThat(thing.getOne(), is(5L));
        assertThat(thing.getTwo(), is ("foo"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more how this would work? I tried it. Passing in null is not caught and doesn't throw a ConstrainViolationException.

Comment: @MarkDavoren Actually, there is a confusion between mock and integration testing on this example. In fact, Spring mock testing is being used and expectation is to have validation facility active and running, which would mean integration testing as other classes are also involved.

SpringBootTest annotation is very powerful and could be used for ranges of integration testing. To test a service class, you can specify which classes you want to test, using classes parameters. Then you will have only classes mentioned into the context, which improves context initialization time drastically.

Comment: @MarkDavoren Actually my precious comment is about why this can help, the previous question. I have updated the code snippet with minimum setup to make sure that it is working.